# Why does SELECT results differ between mysql and sqlite?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm re-asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161153/sqlite-exists-keyword-how-to-query-the-highest-average) in a simplified and expanded manner.

Consider these sql statements:

```
create table foo (id INT, score INT);

insert into foo values (106, 4);
insert into foo values (107, 3);
insert into foo values (106, 5);
insert into foo values (107, 5);

select T1.id, avg(T1.score) avg1
from foo T1
group by T1.id
having not exists (
    select T2.id, avg(T2.score) avg2
    from foo T2
    group by T2.id
    having avg2 > avg1);
```

Using sqlite, the `select` statement returns:

```
id          avg1      
----------  ----------
106         4.5       
107         4.0
```

and mysql returns:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | avg1   |
+------+--------+
|  106 | 4.5000 |
+------+--------+
```

As far as I can tell, mysql's results are correct, and sqlite's are incorrect. I tried to cast to `real` with sqlite as in the following but it returns two records still:

```
select T1.id, cast(avg(cast(T1.score as real)) as real) avg1
from foo T1
group by T1.id
having not exists (
    select T2.id, cast(avg(cast(T2.score as real)) as real) avg2
    from foo T2
    group by T2.id
    having avg2 > avg1);
```

Why does sqlite return two records?

**Quick update**:

I ran the statement against the latest sqlite version (3.7.11) and still get two records.

**Another update**:

I sent an email to sqlite-users@sqlite.org about the issue.

Myself, I've been playing with VDBE and found something interesting. I split the execution trace of each loop of `not exists` (one for each avg group).

To have three avg groups, I used the following statements:

```
create table foo (id VARCHAR(1), score INT);

insert into foo values ('c', 1.5);
insert into foo values ('b', 5.0);
insert into foo values ('a', 4.0);
insert into foo values ('a', 5.0);

PRAGMA vdbe_listing = 1;
PRAGMA vdbe_trace=ON;

select avg(score) avg1
from foo
group by id
having not exists (
    select avg(T2.score) avg2
    from foo T2
    group by T2.id
    having avg2 > avg1);
```

We clearly see that somehow what should be `r:4.5` has become `i:5`:

[image]

I'm now trying to see why that is.

**Final edit**:

So I've been playing enough with the sqlite source code. I understand the beast much better now, although I'll let the [original developer](http://sqlite.org/support.html) sort it out as he seems to already be doing it:

http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/430bb59d79

Interestingly, to me at least, it seems that the newer versions (some times after the version I'm using) supports inserting multiple records as used in a test case added in the aforementioned commit:

```
CREATE TABLE t34(x,y);
INSERT INTO t34 VALUES(106,4), (107,3), (106,5), (107,5);
```

Comment: Just for kicks I ran this to SQL what SQL Server would produce and it complained `avg2` and `avg1` didn't exist. I replaced them with `MAX(T2.score)` and `MAX(T1.score)` and it gave the SQLite result. When I created the table with `score REAL` it gave the MySQL result. Perhaps your MySQL schema is different to sqlites?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: can you try adding `as` as in `avg(T2.score) as avg2` (two occurences)?

Comment: Doesn't work. Pretty sure SQL Server doesn't play dice when it comes to using aliases in `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`.

Comment: trying parts of the statement under sqlite I have this `SQL error: no such function: exists`. Keywords that are working under mysql may not in other databases systems. I would personally use the `IN` keyword for testing the results of your subquery

Comment: @Bathz: what version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: The documentation doesn't help. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html - The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value for exact-value arguments (integer or DECIMAL). http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html -  The result of avg() is always a floating point value ... even if all inputs are integers. And while we're at it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1123f/1

Comment: @ta.speot.is: yes I think mysql's resulte are indeed correct; and even sqlite seems to say that `avg` returns a `real`: `select typeof(avg(score)) from foo;` returns `real`.

Comment: It looks like you have discovered a genuine bug in SQLite (which does not surprise me a slightest bit). It is definitely not the precision, because it does not work even when you replace `avg` with `sum`, which does not require division.

Comment: @sixfeetsix I run sqlite v.2.8.17 so yes maybe my advice does not help :) . However in my short dev life I never used the keyword `EXISTS` except for table creation and so on and when reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929/difference-between-exists-and-in-in-sql  I may think it is not the best keyword for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Bathz: yes sqlite 2.X doesn't support that select statement (perhaps because `EXISTS` wasn't supported then...); in any case, I have nothing for or against `EXISTS`.

Comment: Ok, I took a look again with the two keywords versions, and indeed results are the same. Sqlite seems to incorrectly handle whether the subquery or the avg1 variable. Because when I hardcode the subquery result in a `IN` clause or the avg1 var in a `EXISTS` clause it returns the correct result...

Comment: Seems like sqlite team needs a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to mess with some variants of query.

It seems, like sqlite has errors in using of previous declared fields in a nested **HAVING** expressions.

In your example `avg1` under second having is always equal to 5.0

Look:

```
select T1.id, avg(T1.score) avg1
from foo T1
group by T1.id
having not exists (
    SELECT 1 AS col1 GROUP BY col1 HAVING avg1 = 5.0);
```

This one returns nothing, but execution of the following query returns both records:

```
...
having not exists (
    SELECT 1 AS col1 GROUP BY col1 HAVING avg1 <> 5.0);
```

I can not find any similar bug at [sqlite tickets list](http://www.sqlite.org/src/rptview?rn=1).

Comment: Yes I'm seeing something very similar with when tracing with VDBE. I already sent sqlite-users@sqlite.org an email about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this two ways, i'll use postgres 9.0 as my reference database

(1)

```
-- select rows from foo 

select T1.id, avg(T1.score) avg1
from foo T1
group by T1.id
-- where we don't have any rows from T2
having  not exists (
-- select rows from foo
select T2.id, avg(T2.score) avg2
from foo T2
group by T2.id
-- where the average score for any row is greater than the average for 
-- any row in T1
having avg2 > avg1);

 id  |        avg1        
-----+--------------------
 106 | 4.5000000000000000
(1 row)
```

then let's move some of the logic inside the subquery, getting rid of the 'not' :
(2)

```
-- select rows from foo 
select T1.id, avg(T1.score) avg1
from foo T1
group by T1.id
-- where we do have rows from T2
having  exists (
-- select rows from foo
select T2.id, avg(T2.score) avg2
from foo T2
group by T2.id
-- where the average score is less than or equal than the average for any row in T1
having avg2 <= avg1);
-- I think this expression will be true for all rows as we are in effect doing a
--cartesian join 
-- with the 'having' only we don't display the cartesian row set

 id  |        avg1        
-----+--------------------
 106 | 4.5000000000000000
 107 | 4.0000000000000000
(2 rows)
```

so you have got to ask yourself -- what do you actually mean when you do this correlated subquery inside a having clause, if it evaluates every row against every row from the primary query we are making a cartesian join and I don't think we should be pointing fingers at the SQL engine.

if you want every row that is less than the maximum average What you should be saying is:

```
select T1.id, avg(T1.score) avg1 
from foo T1 group by T1.id
having avg1 not in 
(select max(avg1) from (select id,avg(score) avg1 from foo group by id))
```

Comment: That select statement in my question is really not that difficult to understand; I simply want the correct result ;-)

Comment: I contend that it is ambiguous and will provide an indeterminate result across different technologies

Comment: It seems it's not ambiguous to MySql, MS Sql, and now Postgres; and it also seems that the main developer of sqlite is making changes in reaction to the email I sent to sqlite-users@sqlite.org.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this version? :

```
select T1.id, avg(T1.score) avg1
from foo T1
group by T1.id
having not exists (
    select T2.id, avg(T2.score) avg2
    from foo T2
    group by T2.id
    having avg(T2.score) > avg(T1.score));
```

---

Also this one (which should be giving same results):

```
select T1.*
from
  ( select id, avg(score) avg1
    from foo 
    group by id
  ) T1
where not exists (
    select T2.id, avg(T2.score) avg2
    from foo T2
    group by T2.id
    having avg(T2.score) > avg1);
```

---

The query can also be handled with derived tables, instead of subquery in `HAVING` clause:

```
select ta.id, ta.avg1
from 
  ( select id, avg(score) avg1
    from foo
    group by id
  ) ta
  JOIN
  ( select avg(score) avg1
    from foo 
    group by id
    order by avg1 DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) tmp
  ON tmp.avg1 = ta.avg1
```

Comment: I just did; same 2 records in sqlite, same 1 record in mysql.

Comment: Yes your second option I have already served as an answer; please see the question I linked at the beginning of this question.

Comment: As to why the original query doesn't work as expected, I suppose it's a bug, related to how subqueries are handled.

Comment: @sixfeetsix: Does the `JOIN` version shows correct (1-row) result?

Comment: @sixfeetsix: I've added one more version with derived subquery, turning `HAVING` into `WHERE`.